# Jquery Data table Search Option is not enable sorting icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am stuck in jquery Data table. if we use jquery data table then it provide by default search option. But problem  is that if i search particular record and if content is not match or i found single record. then i need to remove sorting icon. it will work but as i press back space and remove searching content then as usual it display all records. But now sortable icon is disable it needs to enabled once again then what is the solution for that.

This is function call:-

```
$('#datatable-information').on('draw.dt', function () {

    disableSortingSearchOption(oTable, 'datatable-information_filter input');
```

This is Function Defination:-

```
function disableSortingSearchOption(oTables, tableClass) {

    if (oTables != null) {
        var rowCount = oTables.fnSettings().fnRecordsDisplay();
        {

            if (rowCount == 0 || rowCount == 1) {


                var oSettings = oTables.fnSettings();

                //Remove sort icon
                $('.DataTables_sort_icon').remove();
                //Remove hand cursor
                $('.datatable th').css('cursor', 'default');
                //Iterate through each column and disable sorting 
                $('.' + tableClass + ' th').each(function (index) {
                    if ((oSettings.aoColumns[index]) != undefined) {
                        oSettings.aoColumns[index].bSortable = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to remove the sorting arrows on the table headers and change the pointer to default when the drawed table has 1 line or less.

On more than one line, the table sorting and the pointer comes back to "normal".

My solution is quite different than the code you provided.

```
function disableSortingSearchOption(oTables) {

  if (oTables != null) {
    var colCount = 0;
    $(oTables).find('th').each(function(){
      colCount++;
    });
    //console.log(colCount+" colunms");

    var rowCount = 0;
    $(oTables).find('td').each(function(){
      rowCount++;
    });
    rowCount = rowCount/colCount;
    //console.log(rowCount+" rows");

    if (rowCount <= 1) {
      //Remove hand cursor
      $(oTables).find('th').css('cursor', 'default');

      //Remove sort arrows
      $(oTables).find('th').removeClass('sorting');

    }else{
      //Add hand cursor
      $(oTables).find('th').css('cursor', 'pointer');

      //Add sort arrows
      $(oTables).find('th').addClass('sorting');
    }
  }
}
```

We need to know the row amount...
To achieve this, we first count the column amount and the whole table's `td` amount.

The row amount is the `td` amount divided by the column amount.
Based on this number, we can add or remove the `sorting` class on all `th` and set the cursor.

Note that when there is no result, there is still one line to show *"No matching records found"*. But since there is only 1 `td` in this case... divided by the colunm count, we have to think about "one or less line".
;)

Have a look at this [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LRzWyL?editors=1010).